# Invertibility of Hessian of continious bounded mutlivariate function

Tags: matrices, singularity, hessian-matrix

I am calculating a density using [Kernel Density Estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation). The resulting density function is a sum of Gaussians with arbitrary $\mu_i$ and $\Sigma_i$:

$$
density(\mathbf x) = \sum_i
{\frac {1}{\sqrt {(2\pi )^{k}|{\boldsymbol {\Sigma_i }}|}}} \cdot \exp \left(-{\frac {1}{2}}({\mathbf {x} }-{\boldsymbol {\mu }_i})^{\mathrm {T} }{\boldsymbol {\Sigma_i }}^{-1}({\mathbf {x} }-{\boldsymbol {\mu }_i})\right)
$$

For this case, or even more general:

If I have (such) a multivariate function that is continuous, which value is bounded (here by 0 and an arbitrary real value), the norm of each $gradient(\mathbf x)$ is bounded: Is the second derivative $hessian(\mathbf x)$ of the function always invertible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is negative.

Consider the uni-dimensional Gaussian

$$\varphi(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}$$

The second derivative (Hessian) is $\varphi^{(2)}(x)= H_2(x)\varphi(x)$ where $H_2$ is the second Hermite polynomial which vanishes at $-1,1$.

**More intuitively: the Gaussian has inflection points.**

Comment: I guess this also is the case under the conditions that I have multiple $\mu_i$ which cannot be all identical and/or that $x$ is multivariate? I was reading up on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saddle_point which led me to my thought (since a saddle point has an indefinite Hessian, but still invertible), but I guess an inflection point is not be confused with a saddle, point, right?